# External Bluetooth Keyboard integration in IOS 7

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, ios7, uiapplication

I need to support external keyboard functionality in my app and need key combinations like Alt+Tab Tab to be detected in the app to trigger some event. In IOS 6 I had overridden the

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)anEvent;
```

function in the [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) subclass to get the key pressed combinations on external keyboard.

But now I am testing my app in IOS 7 and the sendEvent doesn't even seem to get called for any hardware key pressed event.

Any Solutions..?

Answer (score 18):

There is a 100% supported way to handle keyboard shortcuts on a Bluetooth keyboard in iOS 7 using the new  [`UIKeyCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIKeyCommand) class and the [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) chain. [I did blog about this](http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2013/09/19/handling-keyboard-events-with-modifier-keys-in-ios-7), but here's the gist:

Somewhere in your Responder chain add a method for [`keyCommands`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/keyCommands) that returns an array of `UIKeyCommand` objects:

```
- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    UIKeyCommand *commandF = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(handleCommandF:)];
    return @[commandF];
}
```

Then, when ⌘F is pressed (in a text input view) the Responder chain will look for that `handleCommandF` method. If there are multiple definitions, it'll use the most tightly scoped one (eg. the View itself takes precedence over a ViewController).

Do note that this will only work when an input (such as `UITextField` or `UITextView`) is the first responder. If you want 'global' shortcuts in your app you can do the trick where you hide a `UITextField` offscreen and focus on that.

Comment: There is a missing ] (closing square bracket) in the last line.

Comment: Thanks! (padding for SO)

Comment: You don't need a UITextField necessarily. You can create a custom UIView subclass that returns YES for canBecomeFirstResponder:, and then put that custom view in your view hierarchy and set it as the first responder.

Answer (score -1):

One the ways to detect hardware keyboard button pressed events in IOS7.x can be to override the method
-(void)handleKeyUIEvent:(id)anEvent in the UIApplication.

But this is a private method for ios, may lead to appstore rejections.