# How are iOS7 Keyboard Shortcuts Implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, keyboard-shortcuts

I saw [this MacStories article](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/a-list-of-new-ios-7-keyboard-shortcuts/) about some apps adding keyboard shortcuts to iOS7 apps. How is this implemented? Is it a private API that I shouldn't be using?

I've done some searching around the iOS developer library on http://developer.apple.com, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'd bet it's a private API considering that the apps listed in the article are all Apple's apps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152871/external-bluetooth-keyboard-integration-in-ios-7

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder it's not a private API, it's just something I didn't know how to search for. See my new answer.

Comment: @paulrehkugler ahh I see. Nice find. Learned something today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152871/external-bluetooth-keyboard-integration-in-ios-7) for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328601/953105) and [this blog post](http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2013/9/19/handling-keyboard-events-with-modifier-keys-in-ios-7) for details.

Basically, there is a new `keyCommands` property on the `UIResponder` class in iOS7. Override the getter to return an array of `UIKeyCommand`s.

Hat tip to [Сергей Малетин](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904310/) for the comment.